# /usr/bin/file exit status always 0

Tags: files, file-command

I'm trying to use `/usr/bin/file` to detect file types in a program **but** also would like it to report if the file does not exist. However the command always returns exit status 0.

Besides grepping the output, is there a way to make `/usr/bin/file` exit non-zero on file not found? Or is there another command that has this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure the the exit status is 0, I tried the same thing on bash shell, i.e trying to find the file type of non existing file, it works fine and the exit status is 1. Try printing `echo $?` in bash after file command to check the exit status.

Comment: Also, let us know how you are capturing the exit status of command.

Comment: `file non-existent.png; echo $?
non-existent.png: cannot open 'non-existent.png' (No such file or directory)
0
`

Comment: sorry the comment formatting is a little cramped. I'm on OSX, could that be the reason? But this also happens on my build server, which is centos i think.

Comment: Also I'm on `zsh`

Comment: I am not sure about OSX, but i have tried the same on zsh too. It works fine. Check if you have strace command or just install strace if its not a problem. Then show us the output of `strace file non-existent.png`. Also let us know the version of your shell, os and file command.

Comment: @GauravPundir That has nothing to do with the shell, only with the `file` utility. I can confirm that on my system (Debian jessie), `file doesntexist` returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

The man page for `file` on my fedora, which is similar to centOS says explicitly that filesystem errors are not considered as an error in the exit status.

However, it also mentions the `-E` flag which you can use:

> On filesystem errors (file not found etc), instead of handling
>                the error as regular output as POSIX mandates and keep going,
>                issue an error message and exit.

Comment: Confirming this works on CentOS! But not on OSX unfortunately :( I guess I'll just stick to the ruby solution.

Answer (score 2):

As far as other commands, Ruby can figure out whether files exist:

```ruby
File.exists?('filename.txt')
```

You can incorporate it like this:

```ruby
if File.exists?(filename)
  # Use the `file` command
else
  # Handle file not existing
end
```

If you do this multiple times, you can clean things up a bit by moving it into a Ruby method that handles all that and returns what you want.